# Use PHP to dynamically create an external file that combines user input with pre-existing content

Tags: php, arrays

I’m trying to use PHP to dynamically create a .js file that combines user input with pre-existing content.

In a nutshell, the reason for this is that I have created a web-based platform in Javascript that allows people to read short, text based stories, which are delivered like a conversation between two or more people - line by line. From a technical perspective, each story makes use of a single html file and a corresponding .js file, from which content is pulled.

I would like my users to be able to create and share their own stories. In theory I think this should be quite simple, but sadly whilst I know my way around Javascript, I know little PHP.

So far I have put together the form that users will use to build their story. A working example can be found here: http://damian.me/editor/?name1=John&name2=Mike&name3=Andrew&name4=Roger
(I’m using the URL data to populate the form at present)

Submission of this form at present simply throws everything into an array, that looks something like:

```
array(3) {
  ["msgName"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "John"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Mike"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Roger"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Andrew"
  }
  ["msgContent"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "Something that john said goes here"
    [1]=>
    string(34) "Something that mike said goes here"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "Something that roger said goes here"
    [3]=>
    string(36) "Something that andrew said goes here"
  }
  ["Leader"]=>
  string(4) "John"
}
```

What I need to do is find a way of taking this data, and converting it into data for my .js file. So, using the above array, the required output would be:

```
},
'0': {
    'text': "<p><div class=\"user gang p1\"><strong>John</strong><br>\nSomething that john said goes here\n</div>\n<br></p>",
    'passages': {
    },
},
'1': {
    'text': "<p><div class=\"person gang p2\"><strong>Mike</strong><br>\nSomething that mike said goes here\n</div>\n<br></p>",
    'passages': {
    },
},
'2': {
    'text': "<p><div class=\"person gang p2\"><strong>Roger</strong><br>\nSomething that roger said goes here\n</div>\n<br></p>",
    'passages': {
    },
},
'3': {
    'text': "<p><div class=\"person gang p2\"><strong>Andrew</strong><br>\nSomething that andrew said goes here\n</div>\n<br></p>",
    'passages': {
    },
```

You’ll notice that John has slightly different div classes, and that’s because, as per the array, he is the “leader”. So in addition to looping through the user provided data, there needs to be some sort of IF statement that captures that.

So to summarise, recognising that users can potentially submit any number of lines of dialogue as per my form, how can I take the data from the array and output (into an external .js file) in the above format?

The final .js file will need to have a header and footer appended to it, but it’s the above array manipulation issue that I can’t work out on my own.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dumping your input data and stating the expected result does not form a good SO question.  This question is too broad.  Isolate your problems and show your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite risky. I've made a simple example for you to achieve what you wish.

IMPORTANT! You need to sanitize the strings first: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Now for the code:

```
// Your array
$inputArray = array(
    "msgName"=>
    array(0=> "John",
        1=> "Mike",
        2=> "Roger",
        3=> "Andrew",
        ),
    "msgContent"=>
    array(
        0=> "Something that john said goes here",
        1=> "Something that mike said goes here",
        2=> "Something that roger said goes here",
        3=> "Something that andrew said goes here"
    ),
    "Leader"=> "John"
);

// Create the file
$output = fopen("example.js","w");
// a foreach to loop through
foreach($inputArray["msgName"] as $index=>$name)
{
    // We start adding the content
    // You may notice I do not concatinate strings. That is because it uses a lot of memory!
    fwrite($output,"},
'");
    fwrite($output, $index);
    fwrite($output,"': {
    'text': \"<p><div class=\\\"");
    // The if else for the leader
    if ($inputArray["Leader"] == $name)
    {
        fwrite($output,"user gang p1");
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite($output,"person gang p2");
    }

    fwrite($output, "\\\"><strong>");
    fwrite($output, $name);
    fwrite($output, "</strong><br>\\n");
    fwrite($output, $inputArray["msgContent"][$index]);
    fwrite($output, "</div>\\n<br></p>\",
    'passages': {
    },
");
}
// Be sure to close the file
fclose($output);
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. Also, thank you for flagging the need to sanitise input. I am aware of the dangers and will make sure I read up before deploying.

Comment: Np mate, changed a tidbit regarding to the way the foreach works. taken from mickmackusa's answer.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, as I know this is all beginner stuff, but how do I use the form data as my array, rather than the hard coded one used above?

If I post the data to the file, how do set $inputArray = THE FORM DATA

Comment: To answer that question I would need to know how you submit your array.

if you use forms then http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

else you can just make a php function instead and call it from js:
function makeFile($inputArray) {//My code except for the array creation here}

Comment: @user5838024 this question was too broad to start with and is becoming more broad.  You need to do the work and only ask questions after researching when you are truly stuck.

Comment: Fair enough. In case it's useful to anyone else, the answer was $inputArray = $_POST;